# Rank Nullity Theorem application

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that {T $\in$ $L(R^5, R^4)$: dim null T > 2} is not a subspace of $L(R^5, R^4)$

I have no idea how to show this isn't a subspace the farthest I have gotten is to show that

dim range T < 3

But how would I go from there?

Comment: Consider $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)\mapsto (x_1, x_2, 0,0)$ and $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)\mapsto (0, 0, x_3, x_4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question does not lend itself to an application of the rank nullity theorem.

**Hint:** what does it mean for a set to be a subspace of $L(R^5,R^4)$? How can a subset fail to be a subspace?

Note that
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0
} + 
\pmatrix{
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0
} =
\pmatrix{
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0
} 
$$

Comment: So it must be closed under addition and scalar multiplication and be non empty, I don't understand what this is example is saying? Sorry would you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: @Soaps the example shows it's not closed under addition